# hola tengo un problema con mi base de datos

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

como  resuelvo este problema me podrian ayudar porfavor Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión in C:\xampp\htdocs\arath\conexion.php on line 4

Comment: Tienes abiertos los puertos de Apache y MySQL?

Comment: Muestra tu archivo `conexion.php` pulsando en [edit], considera modificar datos sensibles como nombre de usuario/contraseña.

Comment: si ya los desactive